# getting elapsed time of video with media recorder in android

Tags: android

I am using the MediaRecorder and recording audio/video. How can I find the elapsed time of the video? I am familiar with this trick:

```
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
...
long seconds = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 60)
```

but was wondering if there was a native way to do it with the actual video.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works for you::::

```
//If it returns  milliseconds, divide by 1000
int playTime = mVideoView.getCurrentPosition();
```

Comment: i do not have a videoview to use this on unfortunately